# ASP.NET Web Form Modernizr DatePicker

Tags: asp.net, datepicker, modernizr

I am using VS2012 and trying to use Modernizr in a new ASP.Net 4.5 Web Forms application to display the JQuery datepicker if the browser (IE 11) doesn't support it.

I have made sure that Modernizer, JQuery and JQuery UI NuGet packages are installed. In the Default.aspx page I have added the following script block to the first `asp:Content` container.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        alert("your browser doesn't support date input type");
        $("input[type=date]").datepicker();
    }
</script>
```

I can see the alert but the datepicker never shows when I click on the input field which is defined as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" type="date" placeholder="e.g. 31/12/2014" ></asp:TextBox>
```

In a simple HTML page it is working fine and I can see the datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$("input[type=date]").datepicker();` The following script is working fine in IE 11.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        $(function () {
            $("input[type='date']")
                        .datepicker()
                        .get(0)
                        .setAttribute("type", "text");
        });
    }
</script>
```

It seems that IE 11 has partial support of date that's why we need to change the type back to text after the jQuery datepicker is attached to the input.